# Can you help me identify this USB cable?

Tags: usb, cable

This cable has USB on one end and an ethernet-like connector on the other.

The print on the cable reads:

> USB 2.0 Shielded High Speed USB 28 1P 26 2C E52534 D AWM

I want to know the purpose of the cable.

Let me know if you need to know the color coding of the ethernet-side.

[image: photo of the cable]

More photos at http://www.yaplakal.com/forum3/topic357946.html

Comment: Post a photo please

Comment: "ehternet like thing"? high res Picture would help

Comment: Could be a USB data cable for a (APC) UPS, they use a cable like that. Like others have said, we need a picture or we're just guessing.

Comment: I added the only picture that completely matches the description of the cable that I could find on the Internet. If it's wrong, feel free to change it. More photos are available on http://www.yaplakal.com/forum3/topic357946.html

Comment: @AndrejaKo are you saying you are guessing what the cable looks like and adding a picture of your guess?  How do you know the male/female orientation of either end?

Comment: @AndrejaKo We really need a picture of the *actual* cable from the OP to give an accurate answer.  Preferably, one that clearly shows the pin-out on the RJ-45 end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Techie007 says, it is an APC USB data cable in the picture. It connects to an RJ45 port on the UPS and the USB port on the computer.  Common on some small business products and higher end home products from APC

Comment: I can confirm this, this is the cable that came with my APC brand UPS.  It's not USB-to-serial, but an HID-class USB device.  Requires "PowerChute" software on Windows and "apcaccess" on Linux.

Comment: Note that the cable pictured is *not* the OP cable

Comment: @Paul We don't know for sure! I'm in an enviroment with 20+ APC UPS' of different models and the description matches many of the cables... :)

Comment: @ultrasawblade, what does the cable do?! I mean a cable like that for a power supply? what's the purpose?

Comment: It lets you get readings from the power supply, i.e. current watts being pulled, minutes left on battery, whether it's getting wall power or not, etc.

Comment: It allows the computer to "see" the UPS it is connected to and manage it much like a laptop can perform actions based on the state of the power source and battery charge. If the power goes out and the UPS kicks in, the computer will be made aware of this and can throttle it's performance to get the best battery life. It can also shut itself down safely once the battery gets too low on the UPS if the power has not yet come back on.